# How to debug Objects in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm currently Chrome for the debugging of my app. The issue is when i try to print data from 'values' i can't realy check the result from the debugger:

```
values: [
           {shadowH: 101.76, shadowL: 100.4, open: 100.78, close: 101.03},
           {shadowH: 101.58, shadowL: 100.27, open: 101.31, close: 101.12},
           {shadowH: 102.24, shadowL: 100.15, open: 101.41, close: 101.17},
           {shadowH: 102.28, shadowL: 101.5, open: 102.24, close: 102.23},
           {shadowH: 102.91, shadowL: 101.78, open: 101.91, close: 102.52}]
```

And this is the result:

```
[object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object]
```

I tried 'toString()' but no results.
How can i print this correctly on the debbuger?

Comment: are you using `console.log` or some other way to print it out?

Comment: yeah, console.log

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try it with `JSON.stringify()`

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(values))
```

Or directly print that variable instead of using `toString()`

```
console.log(values)
```

Comment: He could also use `console.table`. Since all of his objects have identical keys..